# Cannot read property 'split' of undefined while testing getting this error

Tags: unit-testing, vuejs2, babel-jest

**https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8xDM8U6h9Pw**
This is my string I am trying to split that url from = sign. But I am getting error as
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined**

My code is as follows:

```
getVideoURL() {
  if (this.mealDetails !== null && this.mealDetails !== undefined) {
    // let splitUrl = this.mealDetails.strYoutube.split("=");
    console.log("strYoutube", this.mealDetails.strYoutube);
    this.splitUrl = this.mealDetails.strYoutube.split("=");
    const id = this.splitUrl[1];
    let url = `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${id}`;
    return url;
  }
},
```

please tell me how to resolve that error

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? there is a lot of mistakes I can see right off the bat

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you intend to do .. but how about this?

```
const mealDetails = {
    strYoutube: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8xDM8U6h9Pw"
}

function getVideoURL(obj) {
  if (obj) { // check for non-empty object
    const splitUrl = obj.strYoutube.split("=")
    return 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+splitUrl[1]
  }
}

const newUrl = getVideoURL(mealDetails)
console.log(newUrl)
```

This works great -> https://jsfiddle.net/9r13t4v6/3/

Please use parameters when calling functions ... and to check empty object you can use if(value) ... if it's not empty (=> NaN, null, undefined, 0, false) it will eval as true ..

plus you don't have to use that many variables :) try to stick with as many as possible (-> better readability)